# Why does Facebook Insights report zero app installs?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-insights

**My problem or misunderstanding**: On the main dashboard, `developers.facebook.com/apps/<app id>` the value `Last Mobile Install Reported` is always updated correctly when I perform a new install. However, when I go to `Insights` and click on the `Mobile App Installs` section, the value reported is zero. Why is zero still reported?

**Other Info**

- Under `Insights` -> `App Events`, `fb_mobile_activate_app` is always reported but `fb_mobile_first_app_launch` is **never** reported.
- I did put the my key's hash in the `Key Hashes` section.
- I updated my proguard configuration to include what Facebook recommends.
- I am manually installing the application. I am **not** installing through the play store.
- Sandbox Mode is turned on.

**The Facebook API Call**

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String appId = getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_app_id);
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplicationContext(), appId);
}
```

**Photo showing latest Install**

[image: latest install is correct]

**Photo showing App Events are reported**

[image: app events reported correctly]

**Photo showing zero installs... Why?!?**

[image: zero installs... why?!?]

Comment: I think the problem is that you're manually installing the app. Have you tried installing through clicking via the Facebook app and the play store?

Comment: @MingLi I have not tried installing via the Play Store yet. I will give that a try later. Could you please clarify what you mean by installing 'via the Facebook app'. I have not seen an option for that.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were doing app install ads, which is why I asked you to install via the Facebook app.

Comment: @MingLi, the end goal is to do app install ads, it is just I thought I could verify installs were being tracked by Insights before having to create the ad. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My question is from where to we call - AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplicationContext(), appId);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything was setup correctly. It took somewhere between 72 hours and 1 week for the `mobile app installs` graph to be populated with the install data.

[image: Graph updated with mobile install data]

Comment: Where does it mention in Facebook documentation?

Comment: @Akashsingla19 It could not find it in the documentation. I just periodically checked insights and eventually the graph was populated with data.